# TYPO3: sys_file_reference disable new field in Text & Media

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have extended the sys_file_reference to a new field.
The new field is also displayed in text & media. How can I disable it?
The new field should only be displayed under page ressources?

Thank you.

Typo3 7.6.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the TCA of `pages` and add the field to the foreign_types only there. Check out how I do it in my news extension https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_news.php#L565-L602